# Pattern extraction derived from existing column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to create a new column derived from one of my existing columns. The new column is created by taking the values after the first colon up until, and not including the last colon.

**Data**

```
site        stat    crate   
JJ - site 1 ok      JD1:0055:AB5.30:100 
JJ - site 1 ok      JD1:00AB:AB5.30:111 
J1 - site 2 fail    JD1:00AA:AB5.30:200 
JJ - site 1 ok      JD1:00A:AB5.30:555  
CC - site 8 fail    CC5:01AAA:BA8.40:777
```

**Desired**

```
site        stat    main_cr        crate
JJ - site 1 ok      0055:AB5.30    JD1:0055:AB5.30:100
JJ - site 1 ok      00AB:AB5.30    JD1:00AB:AB5.30:111
J1 - site 2 fail    00AA:AB5.30    JD1:00AA:AB5.30:200  
JJ - site 1 ok      00A:AB5.30     JD1:00A:AB5.30:555
CC - site 8 fail    01AAA:BA8.40   CC5:01AAA:BA8.40:777
```

**Doing**

```
df['main_cr']=df['crate'].str.extract(r':(\d):.*):')
```

I've read the documentation but am a little stuck on the placement of the extraction steps
Any suggestion is helpful thank you.

Comment: `r'[^:]*:([^:]*:[^:]*):[^:]*'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get the result you describe like this:

```py
df['main_cr']=df['crate'].str.extract(r':(.*):')
```

Because `.*` is greedy, it will match all the `:` characters except the first and last ones.

Input:

```
  site  stat                 crate
0    a    ok   JD1:0055:AB5.30:100
1    b    ok   JD1:00AB:AB5.30:111
2    c  fail   JD1:00AA:AB5.30:200
3    d    ok    JD1:00A:AB5.30:555
4    e  fail  CC5:01AAA:BA8.40:777
```

Output:

```
  site  stat                 crate       main_cr
0    a    ok   JD1:0055:AB5.30:100   0055:AB5.30
1    b    ok   JD1:00AB:AB5.30:111   00AB:AB5.30
2    c  fail   JD1:00AA:AB5.30:200   00AA:AB5.30
3    d    ok    JD1:00A:AB5.30:555    00A:AB5.30
4    e  fail  CC5:01AAA:BA8.40:777  01AAA:BA8.40
```

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'site':['a','b','c','d','e'],
'stat':['ok','ok','fail','ok','fail'],
'crate':['JD1:0055:AB5.30:100','JD1:00AB:AB5.30:111','JD1:00AA:AB5.30:200','JD1:00A:AB5.30:555','CC5:01AAA:BA8.40:777']
})
df['main_cr']=df['crate'].str.extract(r':(.*):')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using `str.replace` with the regex `^[^:]+:` ie deleting evertything from the begining until the first `:`

```
df['crate'].str.replace('^[^:]+:|:[^:]+$', '', regex = True)
0     0055:AB5.30
1     00AB:AB5.30
2     00AA:AB5.30
3      00A:AB5.30
4    01AAA:BA8.40
Name: crate, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ok does it also remove values before the last colon? Thanks

Comment: @Lynn why do you want to remove the values after the last colon? The output you want has those values

Comment: @Lynn look at the results I have and the results you have

Comment: [‘main_cr’] column values is the desired format